# Возврат объекта из функции

Tags: c++, реализация

Вопрос по поводу вот такого случая:

```
some_obj foo() {
    some_obj s;
    return s;
}

int main() {
    auto a = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Знаю, что за все время вызовется только один конструктор и один деструктор, а конструкторы копирования не вызываются. Но хочу узнать почему так возможно? Объект создается прямо рядом со стэком 'main'? Если перед созданием возвращаемое значения создать еще один объект то что тогда? Как все это выглядить на стэке?

Comment: В зависимости от выбранного стандарта / компилятора / настроек / рализации some_obj может быть вызвано от 3 до 0 конструкторов / деструкторов.

Comment: @VTT как может быть 0 конструкторов?

Comment: Например когда конструктор встраивается и не имеет побочных эффектов. Проще говоря, все выкидывается.

Comment: надо просто гуглить по словам RVO, NRVO и copy ellision (который в последних стандартах стал обязательным).

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Если у вашего кода нет никакого *наблюдаемого поведения*, то эта программа эквивалентна пустой программе. И любой компилятор имеет право выкинуть из нее вообще все. Вот так и получится "0 конструкторов". Смотрите сами: https://godbolt.org/z/Byeqwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел у себя где объект создаётся. У меня в **main** оставляется память в стеке для возвращаемого объекта, а сама функция **foo** при создании переменной **s** не пачкается с памятью , а берёт место в стеке у **main**.

```
//> g++ -std=c++11 tempobj.cpp 
# include <iostream>
class some_obj {
public :
some_obj(){std::cout<<"some_obj():this="<<std::hex<< this <<std::dec<< std::endl;}
~some_obj(){std::cout<<"~some_obj():this="<<std::hex<< this <<std::dec<< std::endl;}
} ;

some_obj foo() {
  volatile  bool  stacktop  ;
  std::cout<<"foo:stacktop="<<std::hex<<(void*) & stacktop<<std::dec << std::endl;
    some_obj s;
    some_obj slocal;
    return s;}

int main() {
  volatile  bool  stacktop  ;
  std::cout<<"main:stacktop="<<std::hex<<(void*) & stacktop<<std::dec << std::endl;
    auto a = foo();
  std::cout<<"main:a="<<std::hex<<(void*) & a<<std::dec << std::endl;  
    return 0;}
```

Результат:

```
main:stacktop=0x7fff83ef0dff
foo:stacktop=0x7fff83ef0dcf
some_obj():this=0x7fff83ef0dfe
some_obj():this=0x7fff83ef0dce
~some_obj():this=0x7fff83ef0dce
main:a=0x7fff83ef0dfe
~some_obj():this=0x7fff83ef0dfe
```

Переменная **slocal** хранится в стеке **foo**, а **s** в **main**.

Answer (score 1):

Детали реализации есть детали реализации. Например, компилятор может транслировать такой код в некое подобие

```
some_obj foo(some_obj &result) {
  // Конструируем `result` вместо исходного `s`
}

int main() {
  some_obj a; 
  // Здесь объект `a` не конструируется в `main`, 
  // а просто выделяется сырая память правильного размера

  foo(a);

  // Деструктируем `a` как обычно
}
```

И не надо никакого "рядом со стэком 'main'".