# Как именно работает конструктор копии при возврате из обычной и из операторной функции?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор-копирования, оператор-присваивания

В данный момент читаю книгу Г.Шилдта. В ней подробно описывается создание временного объекта с помощью конструктора копирования при возвращении значения из функции. Однако при запуске программы ничего подобного не произошло... НО если перегрузить оператор присваивания (т.е. вызвать операторную функцию), программа работает согласно Шилдту. Почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class sample {
    private:
        char *s;
    public:
        sample() {
            s = new char[7];
            strcpy(s, "Привет");
            cout << "Конструктор.\n";
        }
        sample(const sample &obj) {
            s = new char[strlen(obj.s)+1];
            strcpy(s, obj.s);
            cout << "Конструктор копии.\n";
        }
        ~sample() {
            if(s) delete [] s;
            cout << "Освобождение s-памяти.\n";
        }
        sample operator=(sample obj);
        void show() {
            cout << s << "\n";}
        void set(char *str);
        char* get() {
            return s;}
};

sample sample::operator=(sample obj) {
    s = new char[strlen(obj.s)+1];
    strcpy(s, obj.s);
    cout << "Operator \"=\".\n";
    return *this;
};

void sample::set(char *str) {
    if(s) delete [] s;
    s=new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}

sample input() {
    char instr[80];
    sample str;
    cout << "Введите строку: \n";
    cin >> instr;
    str.set(instr);
    return str;
}

void print (sample obj) {
    cout << "Строка: " << obj.get() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    sample a;
    char s[] = {"Hello!"};
    a.set(s);

    cout << "\n3: \n";
    sample c = input();
    c.show();

    cout << "\n4: \n";
    sample d;
    d = a;
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор g++. Результат выполнения программы:

```
Конструктор.

3: 
Конструктор.
Введите строку: 
Hi!
Hi!

4: 
Конструктор.
Конструктор копии.
Operator "=".
Конструктор копии.
Освобождение s-памяти.
Освобождение s-памяти.
Hello!
Освобождение s-памяти.
Освобождение s-памяти.
Освобождение s-памяти.
```

В части 3, судя по всему, никакого временного объекта не создается. Да, кстати, при выходе из функции почему-то объект, созданный внутри, сразу автоматом не разрушается (Почему?).

В части 4 видно, что при входе в операторную функцию (operator=() ) срабатывает конструктор копии, при выходе из неё он также срабатывает. Другое поведение!!
После этого работает деструктор, уничтожает эти две копии.

Лишь в конце программы очищена память от объекта из части 3. Ну и, ожидаемо очищена память от других созданных объектов.

Comment: Сразу надо заметить что в современном С++ (C++17) все **очень сильно поменялось** по сравнению с теми временами, когда была написана эта книга, в частности **именно** в области возвращения объектов из функций. Дополнительно нужно заметить, что книги Г.Шилдта известны во многом тем, что содержат гигантское количество элементарных ошибок.

Comment: есть такие волшебные слова «RVO» и «NRVO»...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения семантики возврата значения никакой разницы между "обычными" и "операторными" функциями нет.

В языке С++ до версии С++17 в контексте инициализации внешнего объекта, чей тип совпадает с типом возврата функции, возврат значения из функции мог происходить по трем сценариям

1. Базовый абстрактный

   ```
   операнд `return` -> промежуточный временный объект -> объект-получатель в вызывающем коде
   ```
2. "Copy elision"

   ```
   операнд `return` -> объект-получатель в вызывающем коде
   ```
3. [RVO/NRVO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/874596/182825)

   ```
   результат сразу формируется прямо в объекте-получателе в вызывающем коде
   ```

где `A -> B` означает "`A` служит инициализатором при создании `B`", то есть в зависимости от типов и категорий `A` и `B`, может приводить к вызовам конструкторов копирования, перемещения или конверсии.

Какой вариант будет выбран компилятором отдается на усмотрение компилятора. Поэтому даже до стандарта С++17 ожидать какого-то *конкретного* сценария было бы бессмысленно.

Начиная с С++17 первый вариант исключается, но второй и третий по-прежнему отдаются на усмотрение компилятора. Поэтому и в С++17 ожидать какого-то *конкретного* поведения бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample c = input();
```

Здесь **нет** присвоения. Здесь есть конструирование объекта `c`, причем при этом происходит copy elision, т.е. компилятор может рассмотреть, что вы присвоите значение `str` объекту снаружи, и будет создавать его сразу там - как объект `c`.

Причем начиная с C++17 такое поведение вообще прописано в стандарте.

Примерно так. Детальнее со ссылками на стандарт - это уже пусть гуру стандартов расскажут :)

P.S. А зачем вы при присвоении создаете лишние копии?

```
sample operator=(sample obj);
```

куда логичнее было бы

```
sample& operator=(const sample& obj);
```

Comment: строго говоря, С++17 допускает в пункте (3) один или ноль конструкторов копирования, а старые стандарты 0—2...